# fgets skip lines, it doesn't read all lines

Tags: php

I'm new to fgets, I have this code to read the row, but apparently until it reaches that line it will skip for no reason... Here is the data in my txt file that I make it to read.

```
ABCDEF1   SDDFS775A                                        QQ            O9   
ABCDEF1   SDDFS77577432B                                                            3.00                                                                                                        
ABCDEF1   1234567C     newCODE    123456       123456789                        83131          DIED
ABCDEF1   1234567C                                               999999                                9999999  999999                  999999
ABCDEF1   1234567D            20170606                51QAZZ  345DDW                                                  LOVE
```

Code:

```
$handle = @fopen($name, 'r');
if ($handle) {
    while ($row = fgets($handle,4096)) {
        echo $row;
    }
}
```

I can read until this row

```
ABCDEF1   1234567C                                               999999
```

but I can't read this row

```
ABCDEF1   1234567D            20170606                51QAZZ  345DDW                                                  LOVE
```

Any reason why?

Comment: Could the line be longer than 4096 characters? What happens if you leave that out?

Comment: @Barmar I tried, but it doesn't work either... I put 8000 still the same

Comment: As above, Lenght is not required for fgets. So what happens if you omit it?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the character used for line endings. Is the last line being included at the end of the previous line?

Comment: is fgets() required? Can't you use other functions?

Comment: @Barmar I don't really understand what you meant, the data above if you see above... it is all white space

Comment: @Andreas yea I have to use fgets, the current system is using fgets except I revamp the whole system

Comment: So file_get_contents and explode is not an option?

Comment: @N00bMagg On Unix, newline is `\n`. On Windows, newline is `\r\n`. If the file was written on one system and being read on the other, this can cause problems.

Comment: @Barmar it is \n,although the development I'm using windows

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is with the method `fgets`: `string fgets ( resource $handle [, int $length ] )`. The second parameter is the length of the characters that will read. See the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgets.php)

You should leave the second parameter empty. Try this:

```
$fp = fopen("fichero.txt", "r");
   while(!feof($fp)) {
       $linea = fgets($fp);
       echo $linea . "<br />";
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This would only be a problem if the line is longer than 4096 characters.

Comment: @N00bMagg try with something like this. I changed the code